# android saving dynamic view values

Tags: android, view, save, state

From the title it might be a little unclear what I want to ask so allow me to explain.

In my project, I need to make a dynamic view in a while loop. Like so;

```
private void loadCheckPointQuantity() {
    final LinearLayout rgLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.quantityAnswers);

    _answerCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(_answerCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        LinearLayout rgContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
        rgContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rgContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        final ImageView checked = new ImageView(this);
        checked.setMinimumHeight(30);
        checked.setMinimumWidth(30);
        if(_answerCursor.getInt(CPA_IS_CHECKED_COL) == 1) {
            checked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_check_buttonless_on);
        } else {
            checked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
        }
        checked.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txtAmount = new TextView(this);
        txtAmount.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        txtAmount.setText((_answerCursor.getPosition() + 1) + "/" + _answerCursor.getCount());
        txtAmount.setTextSize(22);

        RadioGroup rgAnswer = new RadioGroup(this);
        rgAnswer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rgAnswer.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        rgAnswer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                case 0:
                    checked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    checked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_check_buttonless_on);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        RadioButton rbYes = new RadioButton(this);
        rbYes.setText(R.string.yes);
        rbYes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rbYes.setId(1);

        RadioButton rbNo = new RadioButton(this);
        rbNo.setText(R.string.no);
        rbNo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rbNo.setId(0);

        ImageButton camButton = new ImageButton(this);
        camButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        camButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(70, 70));

        final EditText txtNote = new EditText(this);
        txtNote.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        txtNote.setEnabled(false);
        txtNote.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus) {
                    txtNote.setSingleLine(true);
                } else {
                    txtNote.setSingleLine(false);
                }
            }
        });

        rgAnswer.addView(rbYes);
        rgAnswer.addView(rbNo);
        rgContainer.addView(checked);
        rgContainer.addView(txtAmount);
        rgContainer.addView(rgAnswer);
        rgContainer.addView(camButton);
        rgContainer.addView(txtNote);
        rgLayoutContainer.addView(rgContainer);

        if(_answerCursor.getInt(CPA_ANSWER_COL) == 1) {
            rbYes.setChecked(true);
        } else if(_answerCursor.getInt(CPA_ANSWER_COL) == 0) {
            rbNo.setChecked(true);
        }   

        if(_answerCursor.getInt(CPA_ANSWER_COL) == 0 || _answerCursor.getInt(CPA_ANSWER_COL) == 1) {
            txtNote.setEnabled(true);
        }
        _answerCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    _answerCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

What happens is, There is a field in the databasethat determines how many times the loop should be crossed. A quantity. So if quantity is 5. The components should be made 5 times.

The problem is,

Because I do all that in a method, I can't access the individual views.
For example, and this is what needs to happen in reality as well;

I click a button. Then I need to save all results in the database.
Ie for the EditText's and isChecked's radiogroup results.

The problem is, I don't know how I can access each individual view.
I have thought of several things to solve this. But they all end up creating question marks above my head

I tried, making a class to represent an answer(isChecked, note, etc(with getters and setters)
create an array list, put them all in an arraylist.

this should work. Putting the answers in an arraylist. But that leaves me with the next problem. What i a text changes? How can I handle this?

if I use observables, should I make the answer class observable, should I call setChanges() for every member, and implement observable in the class containing the loadCheckPointQuantity?

I have exactly 0,4 experience with observables.

How would I go about saving the latest data when pressing the next button?

I am absolutely clueless...

Since it might be vague:

What I try to achieve: Save the latest data from all views to the database
how: help needed
when: on button click

The time you took to understand/look at/read this post is highly appreciated. Answers even more highly.

If you need more code or explanation. Let me know and I will do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

I assigned eventlisteners to all things that need to eventuall end up in a database.
On focus change, I save the data to the database. So I don't hold any lists whatsoever holding answers. I update the database on the fly. Unfortunately, it is bad for performance. Fortunately, we can afford this performance.

I tried to run this code telling the while loop to execute it 3000 times. Apart from the view generation taking some time(about 3-4seconds on average), all ran fine. So I don't need to keep track of the generated objects outside of the method. android/java does that for me.